# Pusher JS , displaying same message in two different tabs

Tags: pusher-js

Problem is when I do request to php server , is returning me messages in real time , so when I open page in second tab , and send request from first page , Is displaying same message on the second tab , but i did not request in second tab , or even.
Question does not Pusher use socket_id to display messages ? so why i can see message on the second tab if i did not send request  on the second opened tab . any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Pusher broadcasts messages to all clients subscribed to the channel. If you have two clients that should receive different events then they should subscribe to different channels.

Comment: Sure , that is true , but  here is a problem . When you will make second request in second open tab , your program freezing , till the first open tab not done , his  process. How to a=avoid that ?